# If condition is not working in loop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

if condition is not executed while running the controller file......

Comment: What happened to your code?

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the test in the wrong place. The loop is **inside** the map function. Where you are logging to the console, User is **out of scope**. If you want to check each time it should have been in the map function.

However, if you want to keep only those users with cpu < 50 use an *Array.filter* first. You can still log the cpu < 50 items. e.g.

```
app.get('/view', function (req, res) {
    User.aggregate(
        { $match: { "Host.Host_name": { $in: ["redhat1", "redhat2"] }}},
        { $group: { _id: "$Host.Host_name",cpu1:{ $last:'$CPU.CPU_Free'}}})
        .exec(function (err,docs){
            if (err) return handleError(err);

            var Users = docs
                .filter(function (User) {return User.cpu1 < 50; })
                .map(function (User){
                    console.log('Value is less than 50');
                    return {
                        host: User._id,
                        cf: User.cpu1
                    }
                });

            res.render('index',{Users: Users});
        });
});
```

if you want to return all users to the /view endpoint then comment out `.filter` line

Comment: then you want to keep the filter in (and ditch the console.log).

Comment: No. They are filtered now

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop.

```
for (var i = Users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (Users[i].cpu1 < 50) 
                console.log('Value is less than 50');
    };
```

Comment: maybe use parseInt `if (parseInt(Users[i].cpu1) < 50)`

Comment: Values 72 and 99 are greater than 50 so they would not pass the if condition

Comment: `if (Users[i].cpu1 =99)` always results in true because you are using the assignment operator `=` rather than comparison `==`